# At runtime, how to update a listview control on a hidden form

Tags: c#, winforms

I got a hidden form (ViewRegisterForm) which has a ListView. This form is hidden, but I want to update the ListView from another form (RegistrationForm) during runtime.

To be honest I am not sure what is the best method to approach this scenario hence I am open to suggestions..

```
    private void UpdateListView(string value){
        ViewRegisterForm.MdiParent = this;
        ViewRegisterForm.Show();
        ViewRegisterForm.Location = new Point(10, 5);

    }
```

Obviously this did not work!

Comment: Is this winforms?  It would help if you identified the technologies in use.

Comment: You are not updating the listview in the code, how would you expect it to work? You can create a property in ` ViewRegisterForm` to expose the Listview of it and then you can modify the listview by accessing the property

Comment: So sorry bout that... yes, I am working with winforms

Comment: Is _ViewRegisterForm_ the name of the form's class? You should update an instance of a _ViewRegisterForm_ not trying to change those properties like they were static

Comment: first line is namespace Drivers and the second line is public partial class ViewRegisterForm : Form {

Comment: The code you posted, even if it could work, has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: you missed a step there, but first. what are you updating? the code only attempts update the location

Comment: If it's not visible, why bother?  Use a class and a List<T> to store information.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is the following:
You are trying to reference the class directly without making into an actual object.

Create the *object* first, and set it to the `form` type

```
ViewRegisterForm VRF = new ViewRegisterForm();
```

Now you will deal with this Object instead of the class itself.

Use `VRF.PublicObjectInThisForm` to call them

Here is the full example using your code.

In C#:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
 private void UpdateListView(string value)
    {
        ViewRegisterForm VRF = new ViewRegisterForm();
        VRF.MdiParent = this;   
        VRF.Show();
        VRF.Location = new Point(10, 5);
    }
```

In Vb.Net:

```
<!-- language: vb.net -->
Private Sub UpdateListView(ByVal value As String)
    Dim VRF As ViewRegisterForm = New ViewRegisterForm()
    VRF.MdiParent = Me
    VRF.Show()
    VRF.Location = New Point(10, 5)
End Sub
```